# Load Recordset From XML String Without Schema

Tags: xml, vb6, recordset

Could anybody tell me if it is possible to load a recordset  from  an xml string without schema in Visual Basic 6?

For example:

```
Dim strXml as strng
strXml  =  “<root><rec><fld>data</fld></rec></root>”
Dim oStream As adodb.Stream
Set oStream = New adodb.Stream
oStream.Open
oStream.WriteText  strXml
oStream.Position = 0
Dim objRs As adodb.Recordset
Set objRs = New adodb.Recordset
objRs.Open oStream
oStream.Close
Set oStream = Nothing
‘Loop objRs data
Set objRs  nothing
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and your code is very similar to this code from Microsoft support.

```
Public Function RecordsetFromXMLString(sXML As String) As Recordset
    Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream
    Set oStream = New ADODB.Stream

    oStream.Open
    oStream.WriteText sXML   'Give the XML string to the ADO Stream

    oStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

    Dim oRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set oRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    oRecordset.Open oStream    'Open a recordset from the stream

    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing

    Set RecordsetFromXMLString = oRecordset  'Return the recordset

    Set oRecordset = Nothing

End Function
```

Full Microsoft post here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/263247

The OP has correctly pointed out that this restricted to, "**a format the ADO recordset can accept**", and that format has the schema embedded in it.

Comment: Thanks. However, the Microsoft’s code which is indeed the code I had in my example works only for xmls with schema. My question is how to open the recordset from an xml which does not have schema. An xml similar to the example I wrote in my question.

Comment: I didn't think about the line, "Provided the XML data is in the format where ADO recordset can accept". That format has the schema in the xml file. Even if you load from an DOMDocument you would still need the schema defined in the object. I suppose you can still do it, but you would have to hand roll your own method, have an idea of what the xml contains, and iterate the xml nodes

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Has anybody else any idea about  how to open a recordset from an xml string which does not have schema? Thanks